# Does the Deck of Many Things "autodraw" after drawing Void or Donjon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Both Donjon and Void has "You draw no more cards" in its description. However, the [Deck of Many Things](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things) has this "autodraw" clause included in its description:

> If you fail to draw the chosen number, the remaining number of cards fly from the deck on their own and take effect all at once.

**What happens if I declare drawing 3 cards, then I get either Donjon or Void as my first draw?**

After an hour, do the remaining two cards activate at once?

---

This question is **different** from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93838/how-does-it-work-when-the-deck-of-many-things-activates-at-once-but-you-draw-do), which asks "What happens if the autodraws has Void or Donjon included", whereas my question is more like "Do the remaining cards autodrawn if I get either Donjon or Void".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## There is no further autodraw

This is a textbook example of the Specific vs General rule that D&D is built on.

The general rule for the deck is that the deck draws for you if you cannot/do not complete your declared draw.

The specific rule given by Donjon and the Void cards modifies this rule to alter what occurs (namely that you do not draw any more cards).

The Fool has a similar specific rule which increases your card draw by one.

Answer (score 1):

### They take effect simultaneously, so the 'draw no more cards' triggers, but has no effect.

Since the text of the entry for the card says:

> the remaining number of cards fly from the deck on their own and take
>   effect all at once.

In a normal sequence of draws:

`Card 1 -> Effect 1 -> Card 2 -> Effect 2 -> Card 3 -> Effect 3`

So what you would get would be:

`'Donjon' -> No further draws`
[image]

However, when they are simultaneous, triggering all at once, what happens is this:

```
Card 1 -> Effect 1
Card 2 -> Effect 2
Card 3 -> Effect 3
```

All three effects happen together, not in sequence, so there is no 'further' card hanging out there waiting to be drawn. You get all three effects at once.
[image]