# How do I set up a card game using a Deck of Many Things?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

After seeing [this recent thread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154506/what-happens-if-you-just-start-drawing-from-the-deck-of-many-things-without-decl/154507#154507) I felt it might be fun to introduce my players to some sort of poker or native game to the forgotten realms with a slightly tweaked deck of many things. My players greatly enjoy card games and so I wondered if anyone had adapted it to gambling.

Have there been any adaptions people have done to allow for playing games of cards with a [Deck of Many Things?](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Deck%20of%20Many%20Things#content) or does anyone have any experience running a gambling game with a Deck of Many Things who could suggest a good way to play a gambling game of a Deck of Many Things?

I am aware the rules of that deck do not perfectly support card games, and I am fine doing minor homebrews to make the deck more appropriate, such as duplicating the 13 cards to make a full deck.

Is there any official content or unofficial content that would make it easier to play a Deck of Many Things gambling game, such as a full Deck of Many Things, or native tarot based games in the setting, with a D&D game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Deck of Many Things* contains either 13 or 22 cards.

I would assume that most games are played with a non-magical copy of the Deck.

13 cards is exactly the number of cards in one suit of a standard 52 card deck.
Grab 4 of those in different colors, assign numbers for every card and you can play any card game requiring a standard deck.

22 is the number of cards in [the Major Arcana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_Arcana) — a part of the [tarot deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarot). Although mostly used for divination today, it is originally a set of playing cards used for games. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any games played only with trumps, but if you are willing to add the Minor Arcana cards to the playing set commonly used in your campaign, you can use that deck for any game played with tarot cards.
For game purposes, images and occult meanings of cards are irrelevant and only card numbers matter, so all you have to do is assign numbers to cards.

If you are interested in ancient content and insanity, *Dragon Magazine* #77 printed a 78-card tarot-based *Deck of Many Things*. No adjustment necessary; use it with tarot-based games out of the box.